# Using a member of the defined type with the TI compiler

Tags: c++, texas-instruments

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
class In {
public:
  struct Member{
    In name;
  };

    In() {}

private:    
    static const int aCapacity = 16;
    static const int oCapacity = 16;
};
```

When I attempt to compile it I get an error: `error #71: incomplete type is not allowed`

This code does compile with the Microsoft compiler.  Wondering if anyone knows of a way to make this work for TI?

AFAIK, TI uses GCC 4.8.3.

BTW, the actual class is a template, but I am pretty sure that is not an issue here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should not compile : the compiler is unable to deduce the layout of `Member` since it hasn't parsed the entire class `In` yet.

Just declare the nested `struct`, and define it **after** the definition of `In` :

```
class In {
public:

    struct Member;

    In() {}

private:    
    static const int aCapacity = 16;
    static const int oCapacity = 16;
};

struct In::Member{
    In name;
 };
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Although that solves the problem described, it obviously only works if the name member of Member (need to pick better names for my examples), cannot be referenced anywhere in the class In.  What is interesting about the issue is that the Microsoft compiler does compile this.  I assume that is because it does a multiple pass compile.  If nothing better is offered I will mark this as the answer, but I would like to wait for other responses.

Comment: @PatrickO'Hara : you can, just define the functions that needs to use `Member` **after** the definition of `struct In::Member { ... }`

Comment: I am sure that would work, I ended up changing them to pointers which obviously also solves the issue.